# plotting two error bar and a point graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data like:

```
data = data.frame(xval, truevalue, Z, Zmin, Zmax, Y, Ymin, Ymax)
```

I want to plot:

1) xval vs. true value: which is the true line

2) xval vs. Z with error bar (Zmin, Zmax) : which is one model

3) xval vs. Y with error bar (Ymin, Ymax) : which is another model

in a single chart to compare the two models with the trueline in ggplot. How can I do that?

The code that I used to draw only one error bar is like:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = F)) +
    geom_point(size = 2,col="red") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = U, ymin = L,col="red")).
```

The data:

```
     x truval            Y         Ymin        Ymax        Z      Zmin     Zmax
1  3.4    213 128.86930000 120.11653000 205.4866000 3.112501  9.525683 14.46849
2  3.6    129  87.89148000  38.27579000 137.5072000 2.956828  5.745679 17.99412
3  3.8     78  57.50137000  23.90576000  91.0969800 2.849409  5.397766 19.68475
4  4.0     39  37.46327000  16.11152000  58.8150200 4.852883  3.548570 14.19533
5  4.2     30  25.76950000  11.38893000  40.1500700 1.599302 10.008759 19.41591
6  4.4     16  17.15302000   7.33221600  26.9738100 3.276314 10.547963 16.78098
7  4.6      7  12.20945000   5.44359400  18.9753100 2.612158  3.350643 14.79523
8  4.8      2   8.70513800   4.30718800  13.1030900 1.362434  3.694168 18.77055
9  5.0      1   6.29638500   2.62587600   9.9668930 3.264450  8.605551 18.52431
10 5.2      1   4.61383800   1.47820900   7.9794670 2.609167  3.674611 20.42883
11 5.4      0   3.23201500   1.10565400   5.3583770 1.189153  9.257604 14.63917
12 5.6      0   1.92185400   0.57071430   3.2729930 4.349612  7.520131 15.43134
13 5.8      0   1.30018500   0.27379790   2.3265710 3.383852  9.278988 13.68777
14 6.0      0   0.84405380   0.08093337   1.6071740 2.051190  3.678058 12.05836
15 6.2      0   0.53740770  -0.08916827   1.1639840 3.086191  5.330867 17.95173
16 6.4      0   0.23010770  -0.08318029   0.5433957 2.322416  6.803920 21.82935
17 6.6      0   0.15316920  -0.11511460   0.4214530 3.860316 10.824484 21.11373
18 6.8      0   0.15330000  -0.11498380   0.4215838 4.113744  9.305209 15.03836
19 7.0      0   0.07736923  -0.12077150   0.2755099 1.287902  5.236865 13.77305
20 7.2      0   0.00000000   0.00000000   0.0000000 3.930690  6.779964 18.98422
21 7.4      0   0.00000000   0.00000000   0.0000000 3.435644 10.916834 19.18346
22 7.6      0   0.00000000   0.00000000   0.0000000 2.583770  6.425504 15.81924
23 7.8      0   0.00000000   0.00000000   0.0000000 4.931890  9.369571 12.79735
24 8.0      0   0.00000000   0.00000000   0.0000000 2.628918  9.935814 20.37065
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a single chart, or three separate charts?

Comment: @RussHyde in a single chart. Sorry I forgot to write that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't that work? Can you make your example reproducible? We are happy to help, but SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @Axeman Hi Axeman, I could draw only one error bar graph. I am adding the code to the question. But I don't know how to draw another error bar and a point graph as well.

Comment: That's an improvement, but your example is still not reproducible. Perhaps you can make up some example data like `df <- data.frame(xval = 1:10, trueval = ....... )`

Comment: @Axeman I am giving you the whole data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way (without reshaping your data) is to add additional layers.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = truval)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(y = Y, ymin = Ymin, ymax = Ymax, color = 'model 1')) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(y = Z, ymin = Zmin, ymax = Zmax, color = 'model 2'))
```

[image]

Your error bars for Z don't seem to make much sense though.

Comment: Nope the second model is not representative and I have to show that. Thank you.:)

Comment: @gultu I meant that the point estimates fall outside the range (which they probably shouldn't do irregardless of how representative the model is).

Comment: I know that. I did not get my result at that point of time so I just generated that data. I have the full data now. Thanks anyway.